# How to copy URL character values into string

Tags: java, string, http, get

I'm trying to store a value of a GET request into another variable.
When I try to do that with numbers, such a:

```
http://87.103.35.230/test.html?a=20&b=10
```

I store the values using the next method:

```
int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(streamAux.substring(pos1+2, pos2-1).trim());

int valor2 =Integer.parseInt(streamAux.substring(pos2+2, pos3-1).trim());
```

However, I want to do that with characters.

```
http://87.103.35.230/test.html?a=RS232&b=10
```

How do I do that? I tried establishing a string and giving it the same output like this:

```
 String testx = "";             
 testx = streamAux.substring(pos11+22, pos22-11);
```

However, it does not work.

The streamAux object is a string which holds the GET request.
pos11 and pos22 come from this:

```
int pos11=streamAux.indexOf("=R"); 
int pos22=streamAux.indexOf(",");
int pos33=streamAux.indexOf("HTTP/1.1");
```

Can somebody give me a help?

Comment: You shouldn't be hardcoding values like 22 , 11. You might want to use `indexOf()` to get indices dynamically and then use `subString()`. You might also try a regex i.e, `Pattern` and `Matcher`

Comment: Why don't you feed the stream output string into a [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? It is much easier to parse things using it. You only need to use `&` and `=` as separators and you are done.

Comment: TheLostMind, thanks for your answer. I updated the question since I forgot to mention that.

Comment: ARe you open to using the HttpServlet object? You get what you want for free. Or is this college work where you have to do everything by hand?

Comment: Jorge, could you provide some more info? Never used that method!

Comment: Boas João. No it's not a college work. I'm working with a Java Modem so I'm stuck with 1.3IDE solutions because the compiler doesn't allow me to go above. Will it work with that IDE?

Comment: Tuga power! :) Do you want a generalized solution or a solution only for this specific issue? Are a and b examples or always the query string values for that particular http get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. Try it.

```
i=streamAux.indexOf('a=')+1;
j=streamAux.indexOf('&',i);
string a=streamAux.subString(i,j);
i=streamAux.indexOf('b=',j)+1;
int b=Integer.parseInt(streamAux.subString(i))
```

a is received as string keeping 'RS' in it.
b is integer. Hope it is what you want.

Comment: Hey Mohammed, thanks for your answer.
Sadly I got the same result as with my attempt.
Got:
java.lang.NumberFormatException

Thanks

Comment: @LuísTavares Did you get a NumberFormatException for the above code?

Comment: Yes, Mohammed. 
:(

Comment: Hey again Mohammed!
Your method worked, even tho I had to only use '=' in the first indexOf. That's kind of bad because In the real http request I'll have more ='s before the one in question. But I think I'll manage,

Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with `replaceAll()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "http://87.103.35.230/test.html?a=20&b=10";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*\\?a=(.*?)&.*", "$1"));
    s = "http://87.103.35.230/test.html?a=RS232&b=10";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*\\?a=(.*?)&.*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
20
RS232
```

Comment: I only can use "replace()" in 1.3 IDE, and I can't aply that one for strings :\

Comment: @LuísTavares - Wow. 1.3 was released in the early 1600s :P

Comment: Indeed, but it's the only one who is compatible with Java MIDLETS for my device. 

:(